# Alignment of Entries in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, alignment, tocloft, octavo

I would like to reproduce the following TOC in pdfLaTeX:

[image]

I am doing something along the following lines (showing, for example, the second line of the TOC):

```
\documentclass[10pt,largepost]{octavo}%

\usepackage{titlesec, tocloft}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\centering\normalfont\large\scshape}{}{18pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\filcenter\scshape\bfseries}
  {\thepart}{18pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[An Invitation to Mæcenas (Odes III.9, E.F.)]{An Invitation to Mæcenas}

\end{document}
```

Which of course does not present the information ("Odes, III.29" and "E.F.") aligned as in the picture above.

[Class octavo](https://ctan.org/pkg/octavo) can be found at ctan.

Answer (score 1):

I found a hack using boxes. I defined a command for chapter with three boxes, one for the titles, one for "Odes..." and one for either "E.M." or "R.F.M."

```
\newcommand*\myc[3]{%
  \chapter[{\makebox[4.7cm][l]{#1}}{\makebox[2.7cm][l]{#2}\makebox[1.1cm][l]{\textsc{#3}}}]{\textbf{\lowercase{#1}}}
}
```